# How to get all values for kendo grid filter multi checkbox when implement server side paging

Tags: kendo-ui, grid

I have a kendo grid and one of columns ("status" column) is set as filter multi checkbox. In the middle tier I call an api to get data by given page size and page, by this way to implement server side paging.

But the problem is that the filter multi checkbox only contains values that are in one page. For example, the api can return maximum 1000 records at a time, the filter multi checkbox only showing the items that in this 1000 records. Let's say total there are 20000 and there are 3 different status - "Delay", "Pending", "Processed". The first 1000 records only has "Delay" status. Then on the grid, the filter multi checkbox only display one status option- "Delay".

How can I show all those 3 statuses? Maybe I can create another api to return all status, but how to modify the datasource so that it will show all status?

Below are the code snap.

UI:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<ExceptionsPerGroup>()
              .Name("gridBatchDetail")
              .Columns(columns =>
              {
                  columns
                      .Bound(p => p.SnapshotHeader_Account_AccountNumber)
                      .Filterable(pfs => pfs.Extra(false))
                      .Title("LOAN NUMBER");
                  columns
                      .Bound(p => p.Borrower_BorrowerName_FullNameToBeParsed)
                      .Filterable(pfs => pfs.Extra(false))
                      .Title("BORROWER NAME");
                  columns
                      .Bound(p => p.PaymentHeader_ReportedPaymentAmount)
                      .Title("PAYMENT AMOUNT").Format("{0:C}");
                  columns
                      .Bound(p => p.CurrentStatus_PaymentStatus)
                      .Filterable(fs => fs.Multi(true))
                      .Title("STATUS");
                  columns
                      .Bound(p => p.CurrentExceptionTypeCode)
                      .Filterable(fs => fs.Multi(true))
                      .Title("EXCEPTION REASON");
                  columns
                      .Bound(p => p.CurrentStatus_CurrentAssignee)
                      .Filterable(pfs => pfs.Multi(true))
                      .Title("ASSIGNED TO");
              })
              .Pageable()
              .Sortable()
              .Filterable(pfs => pfs
                            .Operators(o => o.ForString(s => s.Clear()
                                .Contains("Contains")
                                )))
              .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                  .Ajax()
                  .ServerOperation(true)
                  .PageSize(20)
                  .Read(read => read.Action("GetPaymentsList", "FileSummary").Data("getURLString"))
              )
              .ClientDetailTemplateId("batchDetailsTemplate")
            )
```

Controller:

```
public JsonResult GetPaymentsList([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, string uri)
    {
        try
        {
            var myUri = new Uri(uri);
            var fileKeyString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(myUri.Query).Get("fileKey");
            var batchKeyString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(myUri.Query).Get("batchKey");

            Guid? fileKey = new Guid(fileKeyString);
            Guid? batchKey = new Guid(batchKeyString);

            var fileBatchPaymentTransactionsResponse = ApiHelper.GetBatchDetailByFileKeyAndBatchKey(fileKey, batchKey, request.PageSize, request.Page, request);
            List<ExceptionsPerGroup> listOfPayments = null;
            if (fileBatchPaymentTransactionsResponse.ListResults != null)
            {
                listOfPayments = DataMapper.MapperPaymentTransactionDataToExceptionsPerGroupsModel(fileBatchPaymentTransactionsResponse.ListResults);
            }

            var result = new DataSourceResult()
            {
                Data = listOfPayments,
                Total = (int)fileBatchPaymentTransactionsResponse.TotalRecords
            };

            return Json(result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.LogMessage("FileSummary/GetPaymentsList", EnumLogLevel.Severe, "EXCEPTION:", ex);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by adding an FilerMenuInit event handler, in this handler ajax call a method to retrieve all the Status values.

UI:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ExceptionsPerGroup>()
              .Name("gridBatchDetail")
              .Events(e=>e.FilterMenuInit("InitFilterMenu"))//add this event
              .Columns(columns =>
....
<script type="text/javascript">
function InitFilterMenu(e) {
    if (e.field === "CurrentStatus_PaymentStatus") {
        var filterMultiCheck = this.thead.find("[data-field=" + e.field + "]").data("kendoFilterMultiCheck");

        var url = '@Url.Action("GetStatusListForGrid", "FileSummary")';
        $.getJSON(url, {  }, function (result, status, xhr) {

            filterMultiCheck.container.empty();               
            filterMultiCheck.checkSource.data(result);
            filterMultiCheck.createCheckBoxes();
        });

    }
}
```